# Python Performance: if x vs if x is not None

Tags: python

**Edit**: I actually got the performance by converting to torch script, but `conv2d` is not convertible to bool in torch script so I had to do `is not none` to get torch script to work with facebook's code.

I was having poor cpu performance because from this [conditional](https://github.com/facebookresearch/pycls/blob/484bb29bdcb19f6d3a4ee033e0990df233a4f18b/pycls/models/anynet.py#L217):

```
x_p = self.bn(self.proj(x)) if self.proj else x
```

and in the moment I managed to hack this up

```
x_p = self.bn(self.proj(x)) if self.proj is not None else x
```

which drastically reduced cpu usage. But I've forgot what motivated me to make this change, so I was hoping someone could provide reasoning why this should increase performance.

The context:

```
class ResBottleneckBlock(Module):
    """Residual bottleneck block: x + f(x), f = bottleneck transform."""


    def __init__(self, w_in, w_out, stride, params):
        super(ResBottleneckBlock, self).__init__()
        self.proj, self.bn = None, None
        if (w_in != w_out) or (stride != 1):
            self.proj = conv2d(w_in, w_out, 1, stride=stride)
            self.bn = norm2d(w_out)
        self.f = BottleneckTransform(w_in, w_out, stride, params)
        self.af = activation()


    def forward(self, x):
        x_p = self.bn(self.proj(x)) if self.proj else x
        return self.af(x_p + self.f(x))
```

Comment: The indentation of the code in your link is completely broken. What does `conv2d` returns? It may have a `__bool__` method that is much more expensive to compute than a simple comparison to `None`.

Comment: Note that the two versions of your code aren't entirely equivalent.  False, zero, an empty container, or any other "falsy" value will take different branches in the two versions.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `torch.nn.Conv2d` doesn’t have an overridden `__bool__`, but that doesn’t rule out `proj` being replaced with something else at some point. Can you run a profiler against each version? Also, what’s “drastically”?

Comment: Well.... it's not `Conv2d` that will return a bool, the definition of `self.proj` is inside an if block and it may never be defined.

Comment: @DanielMöller: The point is that `bool` isn’t expensive for either `Conv2d` or `None`.

Comment: I'm not an expert in Python, but there are two things that come to my mind: 1 - Isn't a generic test `(if something)` obviously more expensive than a direct and unique test `(if something is not None)`. One tests far more things than the other. And 2 - The output of the Torch layer is a tensor that can be huge. A tensor is like a numpy array, usually of type float, with extended functionality. May the if be testing each element of the array for zeros and trying to return a huge array of trues and falses?

Comment: @Ry- I actually have upgraded my gpu from a 1060 to a 3090 and now it runs at 100% cpu nomatter what optimizations I make. But from memory I was able to reduce my cpu usage by 25% so that the cpu fan no longer turned on when training.

Comment: I cant reproduce this anymore (I just came back to this project after a while) in the profiler so I'm going to close this issue. Sorry everyone, I should have reproduced this before I posted.